# Data are not distributed across 60 nodes in Azure SQL data warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created a table in Azure SQL datawarehouse with distribution=hash() . The column which has selected for hashing has 1000s distinct values and table has about 7 billion rows. However when I viewed the data distribution using dbcc pdw_showspaceused('), I could see only node_id 1 to 10. Why isn't data distributed across all 60 nodes even though I selected a GUID column for hashing which has way more distinct values? Is there something I can do to force the system to distribute values across all 60 nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can see here which distributions are connected to which node: `select * from sys.pdw_distributions`
If you really want to be sure the data is spread across all 60 distributions, use ROUND_ROBIN instead of HASH().
Maybe you can get more information from this system view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-pdw-column-distribution-properties-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

In SQL DW there are 60 Distributions, but the number of Nodes mounting those distributions is determined by the current DWU level, and can by any factor of 60.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't know number of Nodes are dependent on  DWU level. can you please point me to a documentation? That would be very helpful. 
Also, suppose I load the data with DWU 100 and my data are distributed across 6 nodes. Later when change the DWU to 1000 (Which is qualified for 10 nodes), Will my data be distributed across all 10 nodes from previous 6 nodes? I guess is "NO". All I get is more memory and concurrency slot right?

Comment: "you please point me to a documentation?"

See [Difference between a distribution and a Compute node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-distributed-data#difference-between-a-distribution-and-a-compute-node)


"Will my data be distributed across all 10 nodes from previous 6 nodes?"
Yes.  That's the whole point of separating the nodes and distributions.